# What is the typical prototype for a deallocation function in C?

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, function-declaration

Looking at code on examples on StackOverflow I've noticed two distinct prototypes for object deallocation:

```c
struct foo *foo_create(int);
void foo_free_v1(struct foo *);
void foo_free_v2(struct foo **);

void bar() {

    struct *foo = foo_create(7);

    // ...

    // Version 1
    foo_free_v1(foo);

    // Version 2
    foo_free_v2(&foo);
}
```

The standard library function `free` uses the first form.

Is the second form idiomatic in C? If yes, for what purpose?

Comment: The `foo_free_v2` will make working with **qualified** pointer to `struct foo` quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

The ones that take a pointer-to-pointer do so because they have the added convenience of automatically nulling out your variable for you.

They might look like:

```c
void foo_free_v1(struct foo *f) {
    if (f == NULL) return; // This has been freed before, don't do it again!

    free(f->a);
    free(f->b);
    free(f->c);
    free(f);
}
```

```c
void foo_free_v2(struct foo **f) {
    if (*f == NULL) return; // This has been freed before, don't do it again!

    free((*f)->a);
    free((*f)->b);
    free((*f)->c);
    free(*f);

    *f = NULL; // Null out the variable so it can't be freed again.
}
```

This attempts to protect against double-free bugs. How good of an idea that, is debatable. See the comment thread below.

Comment: So there's a strong expectation the second form will nullify it?

Comment: @IPribec Yep. If it doesn't, I'm not really sure why'd they'd want a double pointer. Unless they were freeing a buffer full of multiple `struct foos`, but if that's what they intended, they would need to also take a `size_t foo_count` parameter.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I presume the first "unsafe" version avoids doing extra work by assuming the programmer knows what he is doing?

Comment: Re “This protects against double-free bugs”: Well, it attempts to. If code contains a second free of the same pointer, it was generally written in the expectation the pointer still points to allocated space, which means that code preceding the second free may be using the pointer, so that code may be overwriting data needed for something else or may be reading memory that no longer contains the expected data. By suppressing the double free, for which `free` might report an error promptly, this allow the error to go undetected longer, causing more and harder-to-find problems.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't quite follow, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Alexander: If a program keeps track of the memory it has allocated and only calls `free` with a pointer that points to currently allocated memory, there is no need to set that pointer to null. That address will never be passed to `free` again. If somebody is setting pointers to null after calling `free`, one of two things is tree. Either the program would never pass the same address to `free` anyway, so setting pointers to null accomplishes nothing; it is overly cautious and wasteful…

Comment: … Or the program would pass the same address to `free` again, in which case the program has a design flaw. Does setting the pointer to null fix that design flaw? Why do we think that passing the same address to `free` is the only manifestation of that flaw? If the program is passing the same address to `free` multiple times, that is likely because it has it in a data structure of some sort, and it is failing to manage that data structure properly. In spite of being freed the first time, the address is still in a linked list or a tree node pointer or whatever…

Comment: … And that means the program is still using it for various purposes. Passing an address to `free` is not the only thing you do with it. You also follow links. So, if a program is passing the same address to `free` multiple times, it is also likely using the address in other ways after it is first freed. Then there are more bugs to be fixed.

Comment: "This helps protect against double-free bugs." hmmm... not sure I can agree. IMO it helps hiding bugs.

Comment: `free(*f);` aint gonna work

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interesting point. I knew it wasn't useful if you have more than one pointer pointing to the object (It's not like `*f = NULL` changes all of the, it only changes the particular copy of the pointer that you have), but didn't think of it this way. Essentially, you either don't need it, or you're hiding bugs.

Comment: Use after free and attempted free: both bugs, both nasty. Don't want either. Outside of this debate, a use for the null after free model could be for optional processing - test for null and do (different) processing if object is present. I'm not suggesting that this is  common, but it is a use case that is outside of the "which is better to catch bugs easier" debate.

Comment: @SupportUkraine *"This helps protect against double-free bugs." hmmm... not sure I can agree. IMO it helps hiding bugs.*  That depends on what you do.  Attempts to free `NULL` can help find bugs if you detect it and log error messages.  This does assume your testing is thorough enough, though.  And if a customer ever sends you logs with that error message in it, in addition to finding a bug you just learned your testing isn't thorough enough.

Comment: For `foo_free_v2` it would be not possible to deallocate `struct foo * const a = foo_create()` without a cast and *UB*, while it would perfectly fine with `foo_free_v1`

Comment: Alexander, For an equal comparison, the first deserves a `if (f == NULL) return;`

Answer (score 1):

> What is the typical prototype for a deallocation function in C?

Pass the pointer. Nothing is returned or rarely used if non-`void`.

```
void foo_free_v1(foo_type *);
```

> Is the second form (`foo_free_v2(&foo);`) idiomatic in C?

No.

Classic `foo_free(foo_type *)` samples:

```
foo *f = malloc(sizeof *f);
...
free(f);

FILE *istream = fopen(...);         
int count = fscanf(istream, ...);
long offset = ftell(istream, ...);
fclose(istream);
```

---

**When to use `foo_free_v2(&foo);`?**

Use `foo_free_v2(&foo)` when `foo` is not a pointer type.

Example:

```
typedef struct {
  int object1;
  int *object2;
  int *object3;
  ... 
} foo_type;

foo_type foo = { 0 }; 

foo_get_resources(&foo, ...);
foo_do_this(&foo, ...);
foo_do_that(&foo, ...);
foo_free(&foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first function

```
void foo_free_v1(struct foo *);
```

the original pointer used as an argument expression is passed to the function by value. It means that the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer passed to the function.

Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer used as an argument expression.

Consider for example the function definition

```
void foo_free_v1(struct foo *p)
{
    free( p );
    p = NULL;
}
```

This statement within the function

```
p = NULL;
```

does not change the original pointer to `NULL`. It sets to `NULL`  the function local variable `p`. As a result the pointer used as an argument expression after calling the function will have an invalid value. That is a value that does not point to an existing object.

In the second function declared like that

```
void foo_free_v2(struct foo **);
```

the original pointer used as an argument expression is accepted by reference through a pointer to it. So dereferencing the pointer you have a direct access to the original pointer used as an argument expression.

Consider a possible function definition

```
void foo_free_v2(struct foo **p)
{
    free( *p );
    *p = NULL;
}
```

In this case in the statement

```
*p = NULL;
```

it is the original pointer that is set to `NULL`. As a result the original pointer does not have an invalid value.

Consider for example a sungly-linked list like

```
struct SinglyLinkedList
{
    int data;
     SinglyLinkedList *next;
};
```

In main you can declare the list like

```
struct SinglyLinkedList *head = NULL;
```

Then you can add new nodes to the list. As the pointer `head` is initialized then the function that adds new nodes will work correctly.

After that you can destroy the list.

If you will call the first function declared like

```
void foo_free_v1(struct SinglyLinkedList *head );
```

then after calling the function the pointer `head` declared in main will have an invalid value. That is there will be an inconsistency. The list does not have already elements but its pointer to the head ode is not equal to `NULL`.

Is you call the function declared lik

```
void foo_free_v1(struct SinglyLinkedList **head );
```

then indeed the pointer to the head node in main will be equal to NULL that indeed means that the list is empty. And if you have a function that checks whether a list is empty you can pass the pointer to the function without producing undefined behavior.